# Is it safe to use ftp_put in place of move_uploaed_files

Tags: php, upload, ftp

On my server, I'm simply unable to use move_uploaded_files function in PHP, it gives me a permission denied warning. I get the same warning when trying to delete files. I managed to alter the delete script using FTP function ftp_delete and ftp_rmdir.

So now I'm wondering, if it is safe to use ftp_put for file upload ?

Comment: No those two things arent even remotely similar. Why dont you show us the code for your upload handling. Id be willing to bet its a path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the file you are moving is the file uploaded by the user, then yes.

To be on the safe side, it is good to have writable temp folder, where you can move uploaded file, process it if needed, upload with ftp to proper place with proper permissions, and delete from temp folder.